# PHP using MySQL returning errors sometimes, and working other times, despite me changing nothing

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having a strange issue with the MySQL I'm using on my site. Some days, in place of my code, I will get:

`Warning: mysql_numrows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in [the current file] on line 14`

The code is the following:

```
<?php

    include("../../configsql/configsemester.php");

    $query="SELECT * FROM duedates_f2011 GROUP BY actualdate";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $numrows=mysql_numrows($result);


    $i=0;

    while($i < $numrows)
    {

        $actualdate=mysql_result($result,$i,"actualdate");
        $duedate=mysql_result($result,$i,"duedate");
        $styleclass="date"; mysql_result($result,$i,"styleclass");
        $today=date("Y-m-d"); //H:i:s");
        $query2="SELECT * FROM duedates_f2011 WHERE duedate = \"" . $duedate . "\"";
        $result2=mysql_query($query2);
        $numrows2=mysql_numrows($result2);

        $k=0;

        if( $today > $actualdate)
        { $styleclass="done duedate"; }
        echo "<div class=\"" . $styleclass . "\">\n\t";
        echo "<h3>" . $duedate . "</h3>\n";

        echo "<ul>\n\t";
        while($k < $numrows2)
        {
            $assignmentname=mysql_result($result2,$k,"assignmentname");
            $duetime=mysql_result($result2,$k,"duetime");
            $coursecode=mysql_result($result2,$k,"coursecode");
            $link=mysql_result($result2,$k,"link");

            //echo "<div class=\"" . $styleclass . "\">\n\t";
            if(is_null($link)) { echo "<li>" . $coursecode . ": " . $assignmentname . " @ " . $duetime . "</li>"; } else { echo "<li><a href=\"" . $link . "\">" . $coursecode . ": " . $assignmentname . " @ " . $duetime . "</a></li>"; }
            //echo "<li>" . $coursecode . ": " . $assignmentname . " @ " . $duetime . "</li>";
            $k++;
        }
        echo "\n</ul>\n";
        $i++;
        if($i != $numrows)
        {
            echo "<hr class=\"nonmobile\" />\n"; //so that it is not displayed at the end, also this must be inside the <div> so that it is included 
        }
        echo "</div>\n\n";
    }
    mysql_close();

?>
```

It should be noted that the code above is part of a page which is include()'d inside another page, which also use MySQL. I have made sure to open/close the database at the appropriate spots in this exterior code, though, and again, it usually works.

I'm just wondering what would be causing these errors to come about, only sometimes.

Comment: you have 3 depths of queries here, i'd start by simplifying the queries using aggregates and joins THEN while through the results. OR use @darkveloper answer and echo the $numrows variables to see why the queries are bombing out.

Comment: simplifying with joins is on the top of my to-do list, when I actually have some time to tinker with it. This was my first time using SQL, so that's why you'll see plenty of places where things could have been optimized or improved. I've currently implemented the error checks, as others have suggested, but since it is currently working, I cannot gain anything from this. I'll have to wait until next time it fails.

Comment: every single connection and query to the database increases delays and load. you will gain speed, stability and the ability to grow your dataset to silly numbers :) oh and sql optimization is fun! - i have been labelled crazy in the past mind you.

Comment: I really like optimizing things, so I'm anxious for some time to be able to do it. Right now, I just have to fix this so my site can continue to function consistently.
I'm getting an error 28, any ideas on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you put

```
or die(mysql_error())
```

before the ; on line 14

you will get the full explanation the next time it crashes

Comment: this is exactly what I have done. Next time it fails, I will hopefully have something useful. Thanks!

Comment: I am getting an "error 28" which apparently indicates some sort of space issues? This seems odd.

Answer (score 1):

You call the function mysql_numrows() but it is actually called mysql_num_rows().

**EDIT**

It seems that PHP also accepts mysql_numrows(), so that is not the problem.

The actual error indicates that there was an error executing the query. As suggested in other answers, you should use mysql_error() to find out what the actual error is.

Your query is not very complicated, is it possible that the table duedates_f2011 does not exist in the database? Or that it does not have an attribute called actualdate? I'm just guessing now :)

Comment: I've just Googled my original function, and it corrected me to what you say it is. But if this is the case, then why would it work most of the time otherwise? (for example, without the fix, it is working now)

Comment: @rar I just tested it, and PHP accepts both mysql_num_rows() and mysql_numrows(). I updated my answer with some other ideas.

Comment: haha thanks, running some of the error catches that others have suggested. Next time it fails, I'll be able to look into whatever error it returns.

Weird that PHP would accept both versions...

Comment: The documentation states "For backward compatibility, the following deprecated alias may be used: mysql_numrows()", so that part is solved :-)

Answer (score 1):

If there are no records returned this can happen, or if the server can't be connected to, etc. I would add this to the end of all your mysql_query() lines to figure out the issue, especially with more than one query on the page:

```
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); // so it will stop execution and output any errors on whatever line is the issue.
```

Comment: My issue with any server connection issues is that other parts of the page, which are loaded from the same table (just displayed differently) work just fine...that being said, I will implement this for future error catching, thank you!

Comment: you could load the results into an array, to have and to hold on the page, and use the same array as the fodder for display in those different places without having to query the db again. Would make things a bit faster too.